# Create random number generator from a top hat distribution

Tags: fortran, random-number-generation

How would I use a random number generator to give random numbers from a top hat distribution in Fortran?
I've seen lots of information about how to make a Gaussian random number generator, but not one with a top hat distribution.

Comment: What's a "top hat distribution"?

Comment: If you have a Gaussian random number generator, you can sample it, then if the sampled number is inside (mean-variance,mean+variance) then you return 1, otherwise, you return 0.

Comment: Unless, of course, you are talking about uniform distribution over an arbitrary interval. That is just shifting and scaling.

Comment: For a given random distribution characterized by some PDF one can find a transformation resulting in a different PDF. So from the standard random generators producing normal and uniform distributions one can derive a transformation producing anything else, including the "hat" function.